# Browser Helper Object doesnot get loaded in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, bho, windows-server-2008-r2, add-on

I have a BHO, which i can see it as enabled in Add On's list. But it does not get loaded when i start my IE on the Win2k8 R2 machines(64 bit).

I have disabled IE Enhanced security as well but no help. The same BHO gets loaded in other machines.

The registry details under (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects & HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID) seem to be fine.

Is there any setting that disables BHO from actually getting loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the BHO's are disabled on windows servers.

To enable BHO one has to change this setting "**Enable Browser Extensions**" string value to "**yes**" in the following registry key:
*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main*

Answer (score 0):

I've found I need to register `HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{GUID}`.  I'm not sure if this is the "right" thing to do, but using RegMon, it's what IE is reading...

Comment: This doesn't help either. When monitored with procmon, a query for HKCR\Wow6432node\CLSID is made - but there was no attempt to load the dll.